# Unable to find UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I'm really just starting to get into this LinkedIn API as well as ASP.NET MVC so bear with me.  I'm trying to authenticate my user, which appears to be working, but when I try to store the accessToken value (which also appears to be valid) I'm getting the error:

"Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found."

The error occurs at the comment "// ERROR OCCURS HERE"

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var claimsIdentity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        if (claimsIdentity != null)
        {
            var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (userIdClaim != null)
            {
                // userIdClaim.Value here is: 5-0Vfh4Gv_
                var accessToken = claimsIdentity.FindAll(loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider + "_AccessToken").First();

                if (accessToken != null)
                {
                    // gets to this point, but...
                    await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userIdClaim.Value, accessToken); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
                }
            }
        }

... ... ... 
}
```

This code is 99% from the MVC application template in Visual Studio.  The only things I've changed are to add the linkedin NuGet package (install-package linkedin) and set up my API key/secret in Startup.Auth.cs.  It's entirely possible (likely, even) that I'm just doing some things out of order or getting the user ID incorrectly.

I've looked at every example and video I can find and still can't figure this out.

Can anyone help me with this user error message, and also, am I just missing some general best practices kind of things?  Feeling lost and frustrated...

Thank you!

Comment: What parameters are taken by `AddClaimAsync`. The reason I can think of is it might be taking some objects and object values and you have defined these variables as var which cannot implicitly convert back to user defined class type

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. I don't think you are getting the user Id correctly.

Try

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(claimsIdentity.GetUserId(), accessToken);
```

instead of

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userIdClaim.Value, accessToken);
```

Comment: The GetUserId()  returns null, and the userIDclaim.Value does have a legitimate user ID (at least I think it's legit - see the comment in the code - looks like others I have seen before). Any idea why the function would return null? Am I missing something before this step that would populate that value?

Comment: See @Brendan-Green answer. You will need to create the user first in your Identity table first once you've confirmed the external login was successful, then use the User Id assigned in your Identity tables when adding the claim. The user needs a local identity AFAIK. See http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/UsingExternalLoginProvidersWithAspNetIdentitySystem.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that at this point:

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userIdClaim.Value, accessToken);
```

The first parameter is expected to be the `UserId` of the user in the identity database table (i.e. `aspnetusers`).

You are passing in the `nameidentifer` from LinkedIn - and thus, that user does not exist in your database.

I think you need to check first whether or not the external user is already registered, and if not, then create the account, add the external login and then add the claim.